# Test suite for GIF containing images using rarely used features

Tags: image, file-format, gif, test-suite

The specifications (plural, since there are versions 87a and 89a) of the GIF graphics format are easy to find in the internet (for those who don't want to google:

- http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif87.txt
- http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt)

As you can see in the specification GIF has support for some features that I have never seen used; I only want to give two examples (for simplicity from GIF 89a):
  - Plaintext extension: on http://www.vias.org/pngguide/chapter11_15.html there is a little bit more detailed documentation
  - Pixel Aspect Ratio: see section 18. Logical Screen Descriptor. of GIF 89a specification

On the other hand, for PNG there seem to be lots of test images available: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngmisc.html (scroll down); the most common one is the official PNG test suite http://www.schaik.com/pngsuite/ that is also mirrored at http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngsuite.html.

What I am looking for is a test suite of GIF images that also/especially contains images using features that are rarely used or often implemented in a wrong way.

The best results that I could find in the internet are the following:

- Images linked from http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Graphics_Interchange_Format - among them images using some not-so common GIF features
- http://phil.ipal.org/tc217.gif (as an example how to use 24 bit depth in GIF files) - linked from http://phil.ipal.org/tc.html and referenced in http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Graphics_Interchange_Format&oldid=411332804#cite_note-8)
- The file http://www-eng-x.llnl.gov/documents/a_image.gif (referenced in http://www-eng-x.llnl.gov/documents/tests/gif.html) claims this to be a test image; for me it rather looks like it is from a time when GIF support was not common in browsers
- Under http://www.fileformat.info/format/gif/sample/index.htm there are files called "GIF Sample Files"; it doesn't look to me that they use more than the "very common" features of GIF

So I could find nothing fullfilling the above stated criterion of a test suite of GIF images also/especially containing features that are rarely used or often implemented in a wrong way.

So: do you know of such a test suite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was searching for the same thing and came across this page:

http://code.google.com/p/imagetestsuite/

It contains test suites for PNG/GIF/JPEG/TIFF created so that they try to achieve maximum amount of code coverage with the least amount of images based on the open source decoder code-bases. The idea seems good, but I have not yet had time to check out the actual images.

Comment: Seems interesting. Nevertheless: while the PNG and TIFF test suites seem to be documented properly, there is no documentation to be found concerning the GIF and the JPEG testsuites. So I should probably try to contact the project owner...

Answer (score 3):

I found this question and didn't find anything comprehensive that I could use. So I wrote [PyGIF](https://github.com/robert-ancell/pygif) and made it generate a [test suite of GIF images](https://github.com/robert-ancell/pygif/tree/master/test-suite).

Answer (score 2):

[Gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) is pushing Gif to its limits. I've got an [image that exposes decoding bug in OS X](http://code.google.com/p/imageoptim/issues/detail?id=37&q=gif).

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a collection of test images for several file formats here:

https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-images

It contains those from the ImageTestSuite mentioned in Leo's answer, along with others from various contributors over the years.